# How to add columns dynamically using AutoTable - Table plugin for jsPDF

Tags: jspdf-autotable

My requirement is to download table in PDF document from UI5 application where the rows remain fixed and the column grows. I am trying to achieve this using jsPDF but I am not able to add the columns dynamically . Can anybody suggest how to achieve this ?

Comment: Perhaps you can post the code you've tried so far? Providing a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help significantly with troubleshooting your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the input array dynamically before passing it to autotable.